# How to plot 3D time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

Is there a package in R that allows me to plot multiply time series next to each other 3D?

Like in the following examples:

http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5142/5619005462_5eab3c8cdd_b.jpg

http://synoptic.weaintplastic.com/

Thanks

Comment: see the `rgl` package, although you'll have to roll your own (i.e. I doubt there's a built-in function that does this sort of plot). I can't help pointing out that this is a snazzy presentation but probably not optimal in terms of conveying information clearly -- the perspective will distort perception (see http://xkcd.com/1273/ )

Comment: by the way, you should also probably say something about what you've tried/where you've looked so far.

Comment: Do you want hidden-line algorithms to be involved?  BTW,  the package `seewave` has some "waterfall"-type charts which may be adaptable to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out chartSeries3d0 from the quantmod package?

Here's an example I found on quantmod.com:

```
library(quantmod)
source("http://www.quantmod.com/examples/chartSeries3d/chartSeries3d.alpha.R")
getSymbols("DGS1MO;DGS3MO;DGS6MO;DGS1;DGS2;DGS3;DGS5;DGS7;DGS10;DGS20;DGS30",src="FRED")            

TR <- merge(DGS1MO,DGS3MO,DGS6MO,DGS1,DGS2,DGS3,DGS5,DGS7,DGS10,DGS20,DGS30, all=FALSE)

colnames(TR) <- c("1mo","3mo","6mo","1yr","2yr","3yr","5yr","7yr","10yr","20yr","30yr")

TR <- na.locf(TR)

chartSeries3d0(TR["2011"])
```